# How to add title for a graph according to user selection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, title

I open a dialog box for the user to choose a parameter and I create a graph according to this parameter.
The user can choose one or more parameters out of the list in the dialog box and if the user chose more than one parameter all the plots will be in the same graph (different color for each plot)

now I would like to add a title to the graph according to the user selection (for example if the user chose parameter A the title should be: A, and if the user chose multiple parameters the title should be: A + B + ...)
Is it possible? and how?

Comment: Add the code you have so far to your question. :)

Comment: Its possible using some basic string concatenation. If you have your parameter names: ['var1' '+''var2']. Its difficult to help more without code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code which seem to do what you are after; I once wanted to do something similar and it worked fine for me, hopefully it's the case for you. I put comments so it should be quite easy to follow/reproduce for your application.

```
clear
clc

%// Generate dummy data
x = 1:10;

y1 = 3*x-2;
y2 = x.^2/2;
y3 = x + rand(1,10);

%// Store data in a cell in a cell array. Easy to access in a loop.
DataCell = {y1;y2;y3};

%// Do the same for the plot properties, title and legend entries.
ColorCell = {'b';'--r';'+-g'};
LegendCell = {'Dataset 1';'Dataset 2';'Dataset 3'};

TitleCell = {'Dataset 1';'Dataset 2';'Dataset 3'};

%// Setup dialog box for data selection
SelectionString = {'y1' 'y2' 'y3'};
[selection,~] = listdlg('PromptString','Select data to plot','ListString',SelectionString);

TitleString = ''; %Initialize TitleString, which is updated in the loop.

%// Plot data
hold on
for k = selection
    plot(x,DataCell{k},ColorCell{k})

    TitleString = [TitleString '+' TitleCell{k}];

end

TitleString(1) = [];%// Remove the first character.

title(TitleString)
legend(LegendCell{selection},'location','best')
hold off
```

Sample plot:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Talma is it something like this you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It seems like what I need. I'll try to adapt your answer to my code and run it. I'll update afterwards. Again, Thanks

Comment: Basically it worked. I had to assemble a list of frequencies, let the user choose one frequency or more from the list and plot his selection. 
code:
% Assemble a list of freqs for the user to choose from
    UniqueFreq =unique(vec);
    [Selection,ok] = listdlg(according to UniqueFreq)
    plot(graph of chosen freq/s..)
    Benoit_11 adapted code